# Classic ASP - Select Value Not being Posted

Tags: asp-classic, request.form

I have this ASP on the form page

```
<select id="per_pre_6" name="per_pre_6">
    <% for i=0 to 100 %>
      <option value="<%=i %>" <%if i=rs("per_pre_6_score") then %>selected="selected" <%end if %>><%=i %></option>
    <%next %>
</select>
```

The HTML (cut down version) looks like this

```
<select id="per_pre_6" name="per_pre_6">
  <option value="0" >0</option>
  <option value="1" >1</option>
  ...
  <option value="99" >99</option>
  <option value="100" selected="selected" >100</option>
</select>
```

So far so good. I then choose another value other than 100 e.g. 90 and I submit the form. On the resulting page I have the following

```
per_pre_6=  CleanSQL(Request.Form("per_pre_6"))
response.Write("("&per_pre_6&")")
```

For some reason, it's showing 100 and not the value I chose. Any reason why?

So I submitted the form and the new value was submitted, which was nice, however when I run it again with the new value being the one that's selected and I choose a new value, 100 is still being shown!

Comment: rs("per_pre_6_score") is presumably a recordset value which comes out of a database.  What does the query associated with the recordset look like. Could it be that your form is inserting new rows but your page is still just pulling the first row?

Comment: You don't have duplicated per_pre_6?

Comment: @John Sorry not sure what you mean. Even with the `<%if i=rs("per_pre_6_score") then %>selected="selected" <%end if %> taken out it still shows 100`

Comment: @OlleR nope - checked too many times to count now!

Comment: John: Since the rendered HTML looks fine there must be something else.

Comment: Cache? What happens if you clear the cache of the browser?

Comment: Is the issue here that the value of rs("per_pre_6") comes out as 100 whatever you input?

Comment: @John yup! Also caching doesn't seem to be the issue

Comment: That's why I asked what the SQL query was.  Somewhere before your select dropdown you should have something like `set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset"): rs.open sql,conn` where `sql` is your query.  I wondered if it could be pulling the wrong row out of your database

Comment: Can you please post the form HTML as well? Also, how you submit the form? Are you using AJAX of some sort?

Comment: @John nope - it submits the right data but doesn't display it. However, I came in this afternoon after leaving it last night and it works. The files remain untouched and it just works!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have method="post":

```
<form action="handleFormData.asp" method="post">
```

If you want to use Request.Form

Edit:
If its due to caching, try:

```
Respose.Buffer = True
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
Response.Expires = -1
```

Comment: Yup - sure does. I have around 50 inputs which all work apart from this one for some reason which doesn't want to play ball.

Comment: I figured when I saw you wrote that it actually shows 100 ;)

Comment: No luck. Baffling. I will need to look at this with a fresh set of eyes tomorrow.